# Is there an etymological (or other) relationship between "amendable" and "amenable"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

The terms "amenable" and "amendable" seem to share some nuances in meaning.

> **Amenable:** Open and responsive to suggestion; easily persuaded or controlled. — **Lexico**
>
> **Amendable:** Capable of being amended, corrected, bettered, repaired. — **OED**

I have checked the etymologies of the two terms in the Oxford English Dictionary:

> **Etymology of Amenable:** apparently < Anglo-Norman amenable (not in Godefroy), < amener to bring to or before, < à to + mener to lead < Latin mināre to threaten, hence to drive cattle with minatory shouts. Compare Scots ca' = call and drive. The spelling amesnable is quite artificial, influenced by mesne, demesne, etc.
>
> **Etymology of Amend:** < Old French amende-r < Latin ēmendā-re to free from fault, correct, improve, < ē = ex out + mend-um , mend-a fault. The change frome- to a- took place very early, being found in Provençal and Italian as well as Old French Already in 14th cent. aphetized to mend v.

They seem to have a different root words and origins, but they seem to share some nuances in meaning (The idea of being changeable; able to be influenced) and in their word structure. I think the terms are related through visceral feeling (and I concede that I could be wrong, even about having a similar nuance in meaning). Was wondering if someone could share more insights about the origins of these two words and their perceived similarity (if any).

Edit: The idea of "Phonesthemes" was mentioned in the comment section. And this is could very well be the reason of the perceived similarity. Quoting from [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/phonestheme-word-sounds-1691505):

> Professor Michael Samuels puts this more simply: 'A phonestheme may grow from minor coincidental identification between a few roots to much larger patterns' (Samuels 1972: 47). The words scamper, skedaddle, scoundrel, scallywag, skulk, scrimshank, skive are all labeled 'etymology unknown' or 'etymology uncertain' in modern dictionaries. They all share in common the meaning 'swift, light movement,' thus associating them with the initial sc- sk- group. There is, however, a further association of 'swift, light movement away from one's responsibilities and duties'; hence, the pejorative sense of these words, a sense that is even present in the original skip 'to skip one's duties.' These additions illustrate well the 'larger patterns' that such a phonestheme may acquire through time, and perhaps scab, 'a disloyal trade unionist,' could be added here also."

Comment: They might have the same *phonestheme* (**am-** or something).

Comment: Looks mostly like a coincidence to me, and you're stretching to find the similarities.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul This definitely seems to play a part in the perceived similarity.

Comment: @Barmar It could be a coincidence, but the concept of _phonesthemes_  mentioned aids my hunch. I have added a quote addressing this concept, on how phonesthemes can grow even from 'coincidental identification' separate from their etymological roots.

Comment: @learner254, Collect more words that start with 'am' and have the same nuances in meaning. (e.g. ameliorate)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Yes, _ameliorate_ does carry the same nuance in meaning. This is fascinating. Thanks for sharing your insights. This proves that the similarity is not mere coincidence.